# Bacula TLS negotiation failed

Tags: ssl, backup, openssl, bacula

Problem with Bacula, the Director and storage on the same host (...151), client on another host (...139). I don't use TLS/SSL between director and client, when i run the job i get an error. How can this be fixed?

***bconsole messages***

```
Error: openssl.c:81 Connect failure: ERR=error:14094417:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert illegal parameter
Fatal error: TLS negotiation failed with FD at "10.7.0.139:9102"
Error: getmsg.c:217 Malformed message: [TLS negotiation failed with DIR at "10.7.0.151:9102"]
Warning: Unexpected Client Job message: 2999 Authentication failed.
```

***bconsole status client***

```
Automatically selected Storage: bacula0-storage
Connecting to Storage bacula0-storage at 10.7.0.151:9103
Connecting to Client Bacula_F13-fd at 10.7.0.139:9102
Failed to connect to Client.
```

**Bacula-dir.conf**

```
    Director {                                                          
      Name = bacula0-dir
      DIRport = 9101
      QueryFile = "/usr/local/share/bacula/query.sql"
      WorkingDirectory = "/var/db/bacula"
      PidDirectory = "/var/run"
      Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 2
      Password = "console-pass"                                         
      Messages = Daemon
      DirAddress = 10.7.0.151
    }
    
    Catalog {                           
      Name = MyCatalog
      dbname = "bacula"; dbuser = "bacula"; dbpassword = "999"; dbport=5432; dbaddress = 127.0.0.1;
    }
    
    Console {                                   
      Name = bacula0-mon
      Password = "console-pass"
      CommandACL = status, .status
    }
##########Client_configuration##############################
Client {                   
      Name = Bacula_F13-fd
      Address = 10.7.0.139
      FDPort = 9102
      Catalog = MyCatalog
      Password = "cleint_Bacula_F13"           # password for FileDaemon
      File Retention = 60 days                 # 60 days
      Job Retention = 6 months                 # six months
      AutoPrune = yes                          # Prune expired Jobs/Files
      TLS Enable = no
      TLS Require = no
      TLS Verify Peer = no
    }
    
    Storage {
      Name = bacula0-storage2  
      Address = 10.7.0.151                     # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here
      SDPort = 9103
      Password = "device-pass"
      Device = DISK3
      Media Type = FileXXXx
    }
    
    Pool {                     
      Name = File_pool_for_Bacula_F11
      Pool Type = Backup
      Recycle = yes                            # Bacula can automatically recycle Volumes
      AutoPrune = yes                          # Prune expired volumes
      Volume Retention = 2 hours 15 min        # one year
      Maximum Volumes = 4
      Maximum Volume Jobs = 7 
      Maximum Volume Bytes = 1G                         # Limit Volume size to something reasonable
      Label Format = "F11_HoursIncre-"                          # Auto label
    }
    Job {                                                                                                                           
     Name = "Backup_configfiles_Bacula_F13"
     Type = Backup
     Client = Bacula_F13-fd
     Storage = bacula0-storage2
     Messages = Standard
     Pool = File_pool_for_Bacula_F11
     Level = Full
     FileSet = "Configfile Set"
     Schedule = "WeeklyCycle"
     Write Bootstrap = "/var/db/bacula/%n.bsr"
     Priority = 11                                      
    }
    
    Job {                                                
      Name = "Restore_configfiles_Bacula_F13"
      Type = Restore
      Client = Bacula_F13-fd
      Storage = bacula0-storage2
      FileSet="Configfile Set"
      Pool = File_pool_for_Bacula_F11
      Messages = Standard
      Where = /backup/Bacula_F13_configfile_re
    }
```

**Bacula-fd.conf**

```
FileDaemon {                          
  Name = Bacula_F13-fd
  FDport = 9102                 
  WorkingDirectory = /var/db/bacula
  Pid Directory = /var/run
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 20
  Plugin Directory = /usr/local/lib
  FDAddress = 10.7.0.139
  CommCompression = no
  TLS Enable = no
  TLS Require = no
}

Messages {
  Name = Standard
  director = bacula0-dir = all, !skipped, !restored, !saved
}
```

**Bacula-fd.conf (Remote Host client)**

```
# List Directors who are permitted to contact this File daemon
Director {
  Name = bacula0-dir
  Password = "client_Bacula_F13"
#  Address = 10.7.0.151
#  Connect To Director = yes
  TLS Enable = no
  TLS Require = no
  TLS Verify Peer = no
}

FileDaemon {                          # this is me
  Name = Bacula_F13-fd
  FDport = 9102                  # where we listen for the director
  WorkingDirectory = /var/db/bacula
  Pid Directory = /var/run
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 20
  Plugin Directory = /usr/local/lib
  FDAddress = 10.7.0.139
  CommCompression = no
  TLS Enable = no
  TLS Require = no
}

# Send all messages except skipped files back to Director
Messages {
  Name = Standard
  director = bacula0-dir = all, !skipped, !restored, !saved
}
```

Comment: I think the error refers similar to [this question](https://www.backupcentral.com/forum/19/220622/bacula_tls_negotiation_-_maybe_bug_or_documentation_fault) found using Google "baracula sslv3" seems to be a common problem. so I think that you lacked the research requirement for this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error when the passwords do not match between a client and the director, even when you did not configure TLS.

You have a typo in your configuration.

bacula-dir.conf:
`Password = "cleint_Bacula_F13"`

Bacula-fd.conf
`Password = "client_Bacula_F13"`

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading Bacula from 9 to 13 (and Baculum from 9 to 11), I was getting this error when trying to access the web interface (i.e., Baculum). Notably, in spite of that, I was able to open bconsole from the command line with no apparent issues — I think this would fail if the passwords in Bacula itself didn't match. Here are the steps I used to debug it:

1. I made sure the passwords were all the same in the files in the directory `/opt/bacula/etc/`. (In my case, I think I had all the defaults.)
2. I did a bunch of fruitless debugging.
3. I finally edited `/etc/baculum/Config-api-apache/api.conf` like so:

```
# ...
[bconsole]
enabled = "1"
bin_path = "/usr/sbin/bconsole"
### cfg_path = "/etc/bacula/bconsole.conf" # Old line
cfg_path = "/opt/bacula/etc/bconsole.conf" # New line
# ...
```

There were some other lines after this that also referenced `/etc/bacula`, which I also changed for good measure.

In other words, the problem was with Baculum looking at the old Bacula config files (which had a different set of passwords) in the original install location in `/etc/baculua/` instead of the new ones in the new location in `/opt/bacula/`.